# SSH VM in VirtualBox with host Ubuntu16 and vm Ubuntu14

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, virtualbox, ssh

I am trying to communicate my local machine (ubuntu 16) via SSH a vm created in virtualbox (ubuntu 14).

I do not want you to get ip by DHCP, so I created a "host-only networks" with adpter without DHCP Server. But when I do an ifconfig vm does not see the ip and I can not connect via SSH.

I also run the command: `VBoxManage modifyvm "nameVM" --natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,2222,,22"`

My connection is currently asking for the password even though I am sure that I entered it correctly

```
userlocal@local:~$ ssh -Y userVM@192.168.0.100
Password:
Password:
Password:
```

What else I need to configure?

Thank you!

Comment: the problem is really in my corporate network, I will have to wait to see how they solve it

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a bridged adapter for the vm so it gets an ip address on your network instead of the virtual network that VB provides. Then you will be able to ssh into the vm using the ip it gets assigned.

Comment: thanks for you anwser. I tried to bridge, I can see the ip with ifconfig but I can not access the internet, so I put NAT I have access to the internet but I do not see the ip in ifconfig and I can not access by SSH or bridge or NAT =/

Comment: Ok. Lets start with the network adapter for the vm in virtualbox in bridged mode. Start up the vm, verify you can see an ip given out by your network's dhcp server or one that you statically assigned. Can you ping the ip of the virtualbox host machine? If that works, can you ping the dhcp server/your gefault gateway?

Comment: Only with an adapter in bridge mode or only with an adapter in NAT, ubuntu 14 is a few minutes waiting for the network configuration and does not get ip. (It may be that the corporate network has some blockage). If I put those of the packers one in NAT and another in bridge, which appears with eth0 has ip 10.0.2.15 and eth1 has no ip, I can ping from vm to localhost 10.10.20.43 but I can not execute from local to VM

Comment: Sorry, having a little bit of trouble understanding fully. Go ahead and remove the second adapter and just have the first and only one in bridge mode. If it starts up and does not automatically get an ip, you will have to contact networking people to get a static ip and other info. You don't want NAT because you will have to do port forwarding in virtualbox, and thats just another hump we don't need right now. Easiest way is to set up the adapter in bridge mode, get a static/dhcp address for the adapter, and you should be able to ssh in as soon as the ssh service starts on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem is really in my corporate network, I will have to wait to see how they solve it.

Comment: Yes, it most likely is. Please post again if you need more help! Have a great day.